# games object has no attribute 'name' error

Tags: python, list, class, object, record

I have this code below, cant see what I'm doing wrong in getting the data inputted to display. I get the error 'games object does not have the attribute name'. Please help can someone see what I'm doing wrong?(beginner programmer)

```
class games():
    def _init_(self,name,platform,genre):
        self.name = name
        self.platform = platform
        self.genre = genre


    def display(self):
        print (self.name,end='\t\t')
        print (self.platform,end='\t\t')
        print(self.genre)

def getData(games):
    #st=list()
    st = []
    n=int(input("enter no of games: "))
    print('games details are...')
    for i in range (n):
        print ('Games : ', i+1)
        name=input('\tName : ')
        platform=input('\tPlatform : ')
        genre=input('\tGenre : ')
        st.append(games())
    print ("Game Details")
    print ('Name\t\tPlatform\t\tGenre')
    for i in range(n):
        st[i].display()

getData(games)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of corrections:

1. You have a typo in class init: it's `__init__`, not `_init_`.
2. You are appending to your list of games (`st`) empty instances. So change

   `st.append(games())`

to

```
st.append(games(name,platform,genre))  #name,platform,genre here are the values entered via `input`
```

Separately please consider appropriate naming convention for classes and functions. See [PEP8 style guide for Class naming convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names). It will help you in the long run.

Comment: thanks for that! After making those changes I'm getting:     st.append(games(name,platform,genre))
TypeError: games() takes no arguments

Comment: sorry my mistake, I forgot to correct the __init__ and now it works! thankyou!

Comment: No worries, if it solved the problem, please mark the answer as Accepted.